# Remove border-radius on <lightning:input/>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, slds, css3

Is it possible to remove border-radius on `<lightning:input/>`?

Just attaching a css class with `border-radius: 0;` does not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [SLDS's input component documentation](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/#site-main-content), you can easily create your custom input box:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
  <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Input Label</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control">
    <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1" class="slds-input" placeholder="Placeholder Text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

versus using a `lightning:input` component, which in the end, renders to:

```
<lightning-input class="myClass" data-aura-rendered-by="17:0" lightning-input_input=""><div class="slds-form-element" lightning-input_input="">
    <label for="input-2" class="slds-form-element__label slds-no-flex" lightning-input_input="">ligthgning:input</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-grow" lightning-input_input="">
            <input type="input" id="input-2" class="slds-input" lightning-input_input="">
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning-input>
```

Upside of using SLDS custom component:

- granular control over styling
- access to DOM (not in lightning namespace)
- can use custom attributes

Upside of using lightning:component

- includes SLDS styling
- many build in functionalities

Downside of trying to customize a built in component (such as lightning input).

- Custom CSS may break if changes are made to the component in future releases.

Hope this helps you make chose in between applying custom CSS rules to your `lightning:input` component vs using SLDS with HTML.